# Why is std::mutex so slow on OSX?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos

I have the following benchmark: https://gist.github.com/leifwalsh/10010580

Essentially it spins up `k` threads and then each thread does about 16 million / `k` lock/increment/unlock cycles, using a spinlock and a `std::mutex`.  On OSX, the `std::mutex` is devastatingly slower than the spinlock when contended, whereas on Linux it's competitive or a bit faster.

OSX:

```
spinlock 1:     334ms
spinlock 2:     3537ms
spinlock 3:     4815ms
spinlock 4:     5653ms
std::mutex 1:   813ms
std::mutex 2:   38464ms
std::mutex 3:   44254ms
std::mutex 4:   47418ms
```

Linux:

```
spinlock 1:     305ms
spinlock 2:     1590ms
spinlock 3:     1820ms
spinlock 4:     2300ms
std::mutex 1:   377ms
std::mutex 2:   1124ms
std::mutex 3:   1739ms
std::mutex 4:   2668ms
```

The processors are different, but not *that* different (OSX is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2677M CPU @ 1.80GHz, Linux is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz), this seems like a library or kernel problem.  Anyone know the source of the slowness?

To clarify my question, I understand that "there are different mutex implementations that optimize for different things and this isn't a problem, it's expected".  This question is: what are the actual differences in implementation that cause this?  Or, if it's a hardware issue (maybe the cache is just a lot slower on the macbook), that's acceptable too.

Comment: The mobile CPU has 2 cores and hyper threading (and runs at half the speed but that's probably less of an issue). The desktop CPU has 4 real cores.. that seems an *extremely* big difference.

Comment: Which standard C++ library are you linked against? libstdc++ or libc++?

Comment: libc++ on osx, libstdc++ on linux

Comment: The biggest difference is probably that on MacOS X nobody cares. Your code is written in Objective-C, atomic setters for object properties are fast, and @synchronized is fast. There have always been atomic set/add/or operations. And there's the possibility that the code isn't optimised for pathological cases, but for the usual case.

Comment: This is almost certainly mostly due to one lock being fair (i.e. waking waiting threads in FIFO order) and the other not. Uncontended acquisition time should be a lot better on more recent OS versions though. (though if the Linux std::mutex *is* in fact a fair lock, that's very impressive)

Answer (score 13):

You're just measuring the library's choice of trading off throughput for fairness. The benchmark is heavily artificial and penalizes any attempt to provide any fairness at all.

The implementation can do two things. It can let the same thread get the mutex twice in a row, or it can change which thread gets the mutex. This benchmark heavily penalizes a change in threads because the context switch takes time and because ping-ponging the mutex and `val` from cache to cache takes time.

Most likely, this is just showing the different trade-offs that implementations have to make. It heavily rewards implementations that prefer to give the mutex back to the thread that last held it. The benchmark even rewards implementations that waste CPU to do that! It even rewards implementations that waste CPU to avoid context switches, even when there's other useful work the CPU could do! It also doesn't penalize the implementation for inter-core traffic which can slow down other unrelated threads.

Also, people who implement mutexes generally presume that performance in the uncontended case is more important than performance in the contended case. There are numerous tradeoffs you can make between these cases, such as presuming that there might be a thread waiting or specifically checking if there is. The benchmark tests only (or at least, almost only) the case that is typically traded off in favor of the case presumed more common.

Bluntly, this is a senseless benchmark that is incapable of identifying a problem.

The specific explanation is almost certainly that the Linux implementation is a spinlock/futex hybrid while the OSX implementation is conventional, equivalent to locking a kernel object. The spinlock portion of the Linux implementation favors allowing the same thread that just released the mutex to lock it again, which your benchmark heavily rewards.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you don't understand. How you make those tradeoffs determines how you will perform on this benchmark. Different implementations make those tradeoffs differently. You say it seems like a problem, and I'm explaining why it's not a problem (except in the benchmark).

Comment: I am asking what the differences are, and your answer is "there are some".  I didn't say it's a problem, I said it's slower.

Comment: You asked the source of the slowness, and I correctly explained that the source of the slowness is deficiencies in the benchmark.

Comment: No, you said the benchmark is measuring something that isn't useful to measure.  That is true but it doesn't invalidate the results.

Maybe the issue is that the OSX machine's context switching is far slower and it isn't a library issue though.

Comment: @leif There's no "issue", that's what I'm trying to tell you. You are seeing 100% reasonable and expected results.

Comment: Of course they're reasonable and expected.  I was hoping someone could point to something in the libc++ implementation and say "look, it's doing this extra thing, that's why" and maybe someone will, but your answer is still vague and unhelpful.

Comment: "*Of course they're reasonable and expected.*" Well, now you've changed the question because you didn't like the answer to your original question. That's progress though; now, I hope, you understand that your benchmark is not a sensible way of evaluating the performance or quality of a mutex implementation. The specific explanation is almost certainly that the Linux implementation is a spinlock/futex hybrid while the OSX implementation is conventional, equivalent to locking a kernel object. (See updates.)

Comment: Never changed anything, just took a while to articulate properly I guess.  Then the right answer is much simpler than what you wrote: "the osx mutex is not adaptive".

Comment: @leif Yes, I think that sums it up. (Note that that's not necessarily a bad thing. It's a tradeoff.)

Comment: David is basically correct, but it doesn't really mean that Linux chooses a different strategy whereby it's faster in some cases or slower in others.  Mutexes in OSX are drastically slower, uncontended or contended, because it has to send IPC messages.  Even if you added a futex-like implementation, the contended case would still be slower.  There shouldn't be anything specifically slow about libc++'s implementation.  If you were to compile libc++ on Linux, your benchmark would still show std::mutex being faster than the same implementation on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the same STL implementation on both systems. This could either be an issue in libc++ or in pthread_mutex_*().

What the other posters are saying about mutex locks being conventional on OS X is a complete lie, however. Yes, Mach locksets and semaphores require system calls for every operation. But unless you explicitly use lockset or semaphore Mach APIs, then these ARE NOT USED in your application.

OS X's libpthread uses __psynch_* BSD system calls, which remotely match Linux futexes. In the uncontended case, libpthread makes no system call to acquire the mutex. Only an instruction such as cmpxchg is used.

Source: libpthread source code and my own knowledge (I'm the developer of Darling).

Answer (score 1):

David Schwartz is basically correct, except for the throughput/adaptiveness comment.  It is actually much faster on Linux because it uses a futex & the overhead of a contended call is much smaller.  What this means is that in the uncontended case, it simply does a function call, atomic operation & returns.  If most of your locks are uncontended (which is usually the typical behaviour you'll see in many real-world programs), acquiring a lock is basically free.  Even in the contended case, it's basically a function call, syscall + atomic operation + adding 1 thread to a list (the syscall being the expensive part of the operation).  If the mutex is released during the syscall, then the function returns right away without enqueuing onto a wait-list.

On OSX, there is no futex.  Acquiring a mutex requires **always** talking to the kernel.  Moreover, OSX is a micro-kernel hybrid.  That means to talk to the kernel, you need to send it a message.  This means you do data marshalling, syscall, copy the data to a separate buffer.  Then at some point the kernel comes by, unmarshalls the data & acquires the lock & sends you back a message.  Thus in the uncontended case, it's *much* heavier-weight.  In the contended case, it depends on how long you're blocked waiting for a lock: the longer you wait, the cheaper your lock operation becomes when amortized across total runtime.

On OSX, there is a much faster mechanism called dispatch queues, but it requires re-thinking how your program works.  In addition to using lock-free synchronization (i.e. uncontended cases never jump to the kernel), they also do thread pooling & job scheduling.  Additionally, they provide asynchronous dispatch which lets you schedule a job without needing to wait for a lock.

Comment: It is NOT true that acquiring a mutex on OS X always requires a kernel call. If you checked the source code, you would notice that an atomic swap is always attempted before making a __psynch_* system call, which more or less matches futexes or Linux.

It is also not true that OS X is a micro kernel. Just because they put some Mach code into XNU doesn't make it one.

And finally, message sending only involves Mach server calls - i.e. not BSD syscalls such as __psynch_* or Mach syscalls such as semaphore_wait.