# Condition variables with reasonable performance on OSX

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, mutex

I'm writing a sizable multithreaded program in c++11, and am attempting to maintain compatibility with linux and OS X.  A few weeks back I noticed that the OSX performance was abysmal, and through some reading discovered that this is because the OSX implementation of sad::mutex has, essentially, unacceptable performance under contention.  I replaced my use of std::mutex on that platform with a spin lock impl I found on SO.  Anyway, I'm now in a situation that is similar, except that I want to use a condition variable.  Now, the sip lock, mutex replacement I'm using isn't completely compatible with std::mutex, and therefore can't be used with condition variables. Does anyone know of a strategy or library to obtain the condition variable functionalty (with reasonable perfirmance) on OSX (I only care about 10.10 and up if that matters).

Comment: Have you tried pthreads (`pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t`)?

Comment: @KenThomases that would be what `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, etc... wrap on the clang 3.5 C++11 implementation on OS X. I' more curious what the OP is doing that is exhibiting "abysmal" performance, as BSD pthread primitives are typically reasonably performant if used properly.

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear if the performance problem came from the pthreads routines or the wrapper.

Comment: If it helps, I was seeing an issue just like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899053/why-is-stdmutex-so-slow-on-osx) and was adopting the solution there.  The code that was causing problems for me was (https://github.com/kingsfordgroup/sailfish/blob/develop/include/ClusterForest.hpp) but the context is somewhat difficult to explain (and domain specific).

Comment: To answer @KenThomases, that isn't clear to me either --- I was using the standard library facilities, and assume that the issue was a result of the underlying implementation.  To provide some more context (on why I want a condition variable here), I have a SPSC work queue, where, in certain cases, the consumer becomes starved.  The producer is limited by file i/o, and I'd rather have the consumer sleep until there is work to be done than busy wait on the queue.

Comment: For a producer-consumer situation, perhaps a dispatch semaphore (`dispatch_semaphore_t`) would work. That should be user-space unless/until the consumer must sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. In a nutshell, as you noted prior to OSX 10.12, osx used fair locks for pthreads mutex, which can lead to more context switching and is thus less performant under high contention workloads. As of 10.12+, this is no longer an issue, because not only was `os_unfair_lock` introduced, but the deafult for pthreads mutex was also changed to an unfair policy.

So if you're targeting 10.12+ this is no longer an issue. However, let's assume you're targeting an older platform. Your best option is likely to use a 3rd party mutex library, such as abseil's mutex (C++), nsync (C), or parking lot (Rust). You might think that these just defer to pthreads under the hood. This is not the case, unlike `std::mutex` which is usually a wrapper around pthreads, these libraries implement their own mutex locking, using a signaling primitive to create a "wait queue" of blocked threads (e.g. a per-thread semaphore) which can be signalled to resume in whatever order the mutex library sees fit (abseil mutex is "eventually fair" I believe).

That is to say, you don't have to be restricted to spinlocks, you can have your cake and eat it too (efficient mutex implementation on older osx without spinning) by using one of the above libraries. And it's not just mutexes, they also provide condition variable support, building upon the same signaling primitive/wait queue abstraction.

Now you may be wondering about the "sigaling primitve" I mentioned. It's true, if you want to implement mutexes in an efficient fashion (non-spinlock) ultimately you need the support of the OS to have a way to block and unblock threads. NSync offers 3 options for the primitive, Futexes (linux only), condition variables (as implemented by phtreads), or semaphores (on osx, grand central dispatch provides very efficient semaphores). The GCD implementation should work great on mac, but even if you used the condition variables, it's actually probably wouldn't be too bad. Fair mutexes are only bad under high contention, and here the mutex protecting the condition variable is itself shortly held, and is interacted with only when a thread becomes blocked or unblocked.

One caveat though is that on 10.10+, Apple started using QoS more heavily. Default pthreads have a behavior where when a high-priority thread is blocked on a low-priority thread, the QoS is donated to the low-priority thread. This also helps prevent priority inversion. When you're using 3rd party mutex libraries, you don't get this behavior of QoS transfer (abseil mutex will try to schedule threads with higher priority in front of those with lower priority in the wait queue, but I don't believe it actually changes the QoS of the thread.)

Comment: For more info on how to implement condition vars (windows xp didn't have cvars at all!): https://web.archive.org/web/20161004042656/http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/win32-cv-1.html and https://www.remlab.net/op/futex-condvar.shtml

For info on unfair_lock on newer osx (which comes with an undocumented private futex api https://shift.click/blog/futex-like-apis/

Comment: And finally some general reading on futexes in general (if you master a futex as the signaling primitive, you can see how to implement other abstractions with it): https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/basics-of-futexes/ https://tavianator.com/2023/futex.html http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/the_futex.html https://webkit.org/blog/6161/locking-in-webkit/